# QGIS Layer Tree API crashing when removing layer

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, layertree

I'd like to change the order of layers in my layers panel using Python in the Python Console (this is a for a script not a plugin).

Following a blog post [here](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/) on the Layer Tree API for QGIS, the following code causea QGIS to crash:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
testClone = root.children()[0]
root.insertChildNode(1, testClone)
myLayer = root.children()[0]
root.removeChildNode(myLayer)
```

I've tested this on QGIS 3.4.15 and 3.8.3. Both crash. Manually removing the original layer also causes a crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like this:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

test = root.children()[0]
testClone = test.clone()

root.insertChildNode(1, testClone)
root.removeChildNode(test)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I missed the .clone()